# AndEngine Applying Transparancy to AndEngine View

Tags: android, transparency, andengine

I am developing a game with the help of andEngine in Android.
I have defined background in layout xml and trying to put some component on the screen using AndEngine.
But the AndEngine captured area is not transparent. All the background captured by AndEngine goes black.
I am using org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView in xml and LayoutGameActivity in code.

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.